# RiotJs - How to access object bind by RiotJs using each={}?

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I'm having this simple `<input>` radio user choice.

```
<sample>
  <ul>
    <li each={ techs }>
        <input 
            type='radio' 
            name='dev_choice' 
            value={ name }
            onclick={ check_choice }>
                { name }
        </input>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button onclick={ check_selection }>Check</button>

  <script>
    this.message = 'Hello, Riot!'
    this.techs = [
      { name: 'HTML', rank: '10' },
      { name: 'JavaScript', rank: '20' },
      { name: 'CSS', rank: '30' }
    ]

    check_choice(e) {
        // This is working fine
        console.log(e.item.rank)
    }
    check_selection(e) {
        // How do I get the rank of my selected item ??
        // None of the below is working
        console.log(this.dev_choice)
        var choice = $("input[name='dev_choice']:checked")
        console.log(choice)
    }

  </script>
</sample>
```

RiotJs seems to bind the object used to create the loop to the html objects. However, I don't see any way to access this object from another function.
Any clue would be welcome !

More generally speaking, how to access `this.techs` from `$('sample')` ?

Full running example on http://plnkr.co/edit/2ZuIF4iZQ1WS2CuOOiQb

Answer (score 2):

Use a select_tech variable to get the reference when you select the choice.

```
<sample>
  <h2>{ message }</h2>

  <ul>
    <li each={ techs }>
        <input 
            type='radio' 
            name='dev_choice' 
            value={ name }
            onclick={ check_choice }>
                { name }
        </input>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button onclick={ check_selection }>Check</button>

  <script>
    this.message = 'Hello, Riot!'
    this.techs = [
      { name: 'HTML', rank: '10' },
      { name: 'JavaScript', rank: '20' },
      { name: 'CSS', rank: '30' }
    ]
    this.selected_tech = {}

    check_choice(e) {
        this.selected_tech = e.item
    }
    check_selection(e) {
        console.log(this.selected_tech.rank)
    }

  </script>
</sample>
```

updated example
http://plnkr.co/edit/yfR4v1N4TKi8dH42Poy9?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

I'm using closures for this kind of problem

```
<sample>
  <h2>{ message }</h2>

  <ul>
    <li each={ techs }>
        <input 
            type='radio' 
            name='dev_choice' 
            value={ name }
            checked={currentRank === rank}
            onclick={ check_choice(rank) }>
                { name }
        </input>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button onclick={ check_selection }>Check</button>

  <script>
    this.message = 'Hello, Riot!'
    this.techs = [
      { name: 'HTML', rank: '10' },
      { name: 'JavaScript', rank: '20' },
      { name: 'CSS', rank: '30' }
    ]
    // Use this line if you want no radio checked
    // this.currentRank = void 0
    // Use this line if you want a default value
    this.currentRank = '30'

    check_choice(rank) {
        return () => {
          this.currentRank = rank
        }
    }
    check_selection() {
        alert(this.currentRank)
    }

  </script>
</sample>
```

Please, check my fork http://plnkr.co/edit/TUvaWnL8glRWCoBi549g?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I added an attribute and this works, but seems rather messy:
http://plnkr.co/edit/s1n5EGzrODTw8vCEtWIv?p=preview

```
<sample>
  <h2>{ message }</h2>

  <ul>
    <li each={ techs }>
        <input 
            type='radio' 
            name='dev_choice' 
            value={ name }
            data-rank={rank}
            onclick={ check_choice }>
                { name }
        </input>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button onclick={ check_selection }>Check</button>

  <script>
    this.message = 'Hello, Riot!'
    this.techs = [
      { name: 'HTML', rank: '10' },
      { name: 'JavaScript', rank: '20' },
      { name: 'CSS', rank: '30' }
    ]


    check_selection(e) {
        alert($("input[name='dev_choice']:checked").attr('data-rank'))

    }

  </script>
</sample>
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a working solution, but it would be better finding a tips accessing the whole object !

Answer (score 1):

You find the input selected just using javascript, please check my fork to your original example http://plnkr.co/edit/lgw4TwfJWF5sAEUN4M3s?p=preview

```
<sample>
  <h2>{ message }</h2>
  <p>Check your console!</p>

  <ul>
    <li each={ techs }>
      <input 
        type='radio' 
        name='dev_choice' 
        value={ name }
        onclick={ check_choice }>
        { name }
      </input>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button onclick={ check_selection }>Check</button>

  <script>
    this.message = 'Hello, Riot!'
    this.techs = [
      { name: 'HTML', rank: '10' },
      { name: 'JavaScript', rank: '20' },
      { name: 'CSS', rank: '30' }
    ]

    check_choice(e) {
      console.log(e.item.rank)
    }
    check_selection(e) {
      const input = this.dev_choice.find(input => input.checked)
      if (input) console.log(input, input.value)
    }
  </script>
</sample>
```

Comment: I didn't know about the find function, thank you. However, ```input.value``` give me the ```name```, I'm still not sure how to get the ```rank``` without having to parse this.techs again ...

Comment: instead of `value={ name }` use `value={ rank }` and you will get it

Comment: Actually in my real project, I have complex object in ```this.techs```, and I would like to access several attributes. Therefore it's not possible to put them all in as attribute of the ```<input>```. Any clue how to access ```item```object directly ?

Answer (score 0):

I am 100% sure what you want but I interpret that you want to get the full object of the tech (with name and rank) for the selected object. If so here is what I will do ( [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2ZuIF4iZQ1WS2CuOOiQb?p=preview) )

Basically I add a var to get the selected item for later access.

```
    var selectedTech = null

    check_choice(e) {
        selectedTech = e.item
    }
    check_selection(e) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(selectedTech))
    }
```

Everything else is the same.

Hope this helps.